# Simplify complex Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need to simplify a complex old query in order to filter is with date range.

I got a table with `Tickets` and `TicketNotes`.

I need

- a column with the Tickets count of the day
- a column with the Tickets count with a specific note of the day
- the date

The old query

```
SELECT SUM(IFNULL(qtickets.count, 0)) j, SUM(IFNULL(mtickets.count, 0)) m FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(tickets.id) COUNT,
        DATE(tickets.date) DATE
    FROM
        tickets
    WHERE
        tickets.status = 'Closed' AND tickets.did = 7 
        AND MONTH(tickets.date) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
        AND YEAR(tickets.date) = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
    GROUP BY
        DATE(tickets.date)
) AS mtickets LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        1 AS COUNT,
        DATE(tickets.date) DATE
    FROM
        ticketnotes
    INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.id = ticketnotes.ticketid
    WHERE
        ticketnotes.message LIKE '%https://xxxxx.net/help/tickets/%' 
        AND tickets.status = 'Closed' 
        AND tickets.did = 7 
        AND MONTH(tbltickets.date) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
        AND YEAR(tbltickets.date) = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
    GROUP BY
        DATE(tickets.date)
) AS qtickets ON (mtickets.date = qtickets.date)
```

The goal is to get a result of

```
Date       | M | Q
===================
2020-04-01 | 1 | 1
2020-04-02 | 2 | 1
2020-04-03 | 5 | 2
...
2020-04-30 | 3 | 0
```

With M be the total closed tickets of the day for did = 7 and Q be the total closed tickets that got the note.message.

I need to check the query with one instance of date filter date `BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-30'` and still get the correct three columns.

=======
UPDATE:

When I'm trying to add `AND DATE(tickets.date) BETWEEN DATE('2020-04-01') AND DATE('2020-04-30')` in Gordon's answer, I got other result data from my primary query.

QUERY:

```
SELECT
    DATE(t.date),
    COUNT(t.id) AS num_tickets,
    (CASE WHEN COUNT(tn.ticketid) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS num_with_message
FROM
    tickets t
LEFT JOIN ticketnotes tn ON
    tn.ticketid = t.id AND tn.message LIKE '%https://xxxxx.net/help/tickets/%' 
WHERE
    t.status = 'Closed' AND t.did = 7 
    AND DATE(t.date) BETWEEN DATE('2020-04-01') AND DATE('2020-04-30')
GROUP BY
    DATE(t.date)
```

The result is getting `num_tickets` with wrong data as getting `num_ticket` without JOIN.

[image: num_tickets with wrong data]
[image: correct num_tickets data]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please provide sample data that corresponds to your results.  A clear explanation would help; your query has more conditions than your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

What you are describing sounds like a `group by` with `left join`.  However, it is not clear what exactly you are looking for.  My best guess is:

```
select date(t.date), count(t.id) as num_tickets,
       count(tn.ticketid) as num_with_message
from tickets t left join
     ticketnotes tn
     on tn.ticketid = t.id and
        tn.message like '%https://xxxxx.net/help/tickets/%'
where t.status = 'Closed' and
      t.did = 7
group by date(t.date)
```

Comment: i got an issue with the above query when Im trying to get with date filter.

Comment: @JohnPriestakos . . . The correct thing to do is to ask a *new* question.

Comment: The original question had a date filter. Answer not. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using case for the ehere like

```
SELECT
      DATE(tickets.date) DATE
    , COUNT(tickets.id) M
    , case sum( ticketnotes.message LIKE '%https://xxxxx.net/help/tickets/%' <> 0 ) then 1 else null end Q
FROM
    ticketnotes
INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets.id = ticketnotes.ticketid
WHERE tickets.status = 'Closed' 
    AND tickets.did = 7 
    AND MONTH(tbltickets.date) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) 
    AND YEAR(tbltickets.date) = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
GROUP BY DATE(tickets.date)
```